# I can't access a list from a method in MainWindow class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to C#, but I can't understand why I can't access my list in my MainWindow Class.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<EqualisationSetting> equalisationSettings = new List<EqualisationSetting>
            {
                new EqualisationSetting { LowerFrequencyBound = 20, UpperFrequencyBound = 250, DecibelRatioChange = 0 },
                new EqualisationSetting { LowerFrequencyBound = 250, UpperFrequencyBound = 4000, DecibelRatioChange = 0}
            };

            ItemsCountroller.ItemsSource = equalisationSettings;
        }

        private void AddFrequencyBoundButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            equalisationSettings.add(new EqualisationSetting();
        }
    }
```

It throws "The name 'equalisationSettings' does not exist in the current context    SoundEditor".

Comment: Because it's enclosed in a method scope block, move it outside of the `MainWindow` method in order to use it. [Scope of Variables](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/) give that a read, it will help you get a better understanding about scope of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your variable is inside of MainWindow() method. Try this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<EqualisationSetting> equalisationSettings;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        equalisationSettings = new List<EqualisationSetting>
        {
            new EqualisationSetting { LowerFrequencyBound = 20, UpperFrequencyBound = 250, DecibelRatioChange = 0 },
            new EqualisationSetting { LowerFrequencyBound = 250, UpperFrequencyBound = 4000, DecibelRatioChange = 0}
        };

        ItemsCountroller.ItemsSource = equalisationSettings;
    }

    private void AddFrequencyBoundButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        equalisationSettings.add(new EqualisationSetting();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might use the word 'field variable'

Comment: You will most likely need to make it a public property also.

Comment: Sorry, but this gives me a NullReferenceException, why is this?